# Is the sum of symmetric, idempotent matrices always an idempotent matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I study the properties of real symmetric idempotent matrices presented [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177703592) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2238714?seq=1). Relevant for my question are the assumptions that

(a) $X_i$, $i= 1,2,...p$, are symmetric, idempotent matrices;

(b) $X = \sum_{i}^PX_i$, which is also a symmetric, idempotent matrix.

In their outline of the proofs of some of those properties, [Searle & Gruber (2017, p. 84)](http://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books?action=index&itemId=1118952839&bcsId=10542) state that $X − X_i − X_j = \sum_{r\ne i\ne j}X_r$ can be assumed to be a non-negative definite matix. Since they state that $X − X_i − X_j$ is non-negative definite, I assume they imply that this matrix is idempotent, too. The eigenvalues of a, idempotent matrix are either $1$ or $0$. However, how to prove that $X − X_i − X_j$ is an idempotent (i.e., non-negative definite) matrix?

My approch would have been that

$\begin{align}
\ (X − X_i − X_j) & = (X − X_i − X_j)(X − X_i − X_j) \\
& = (X^2 − 2XX_i − 2XX_j + X_iX_i + 2X_iX_j + X_jX_j) \\
& = (X − 2XX_i − 2XX_j + X_i + 2X_iX_j + X_j) \\
\end{align}$

To complete this proof, one would have to show that all the cross terms are equal to zero. However, this is not covered by the assumptions of the proof. In fact, I found the above mentioned statement in a proof of the property that if (a) and (b) above are given then $X_iX_J = 0$ for $i \ne j$.

My question therefore is whether or not the sum of symmetric, idempotent matrices always is an idempotent matrix and how to show this?

Comment: Have you tried some examples?  Say, $I$ and some nonzero symmetric idempotent matrix?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, you are absolutely right and I am an idiot. I tried different diagonal matrices whose diagonal elements were 1 and 0. In those, admittedly, selected cases it worked. Thanks for this quite obvious counter example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not. Take  \begin{equation*}
I = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Then $I$ is clearly symmetric and idempotent but

\begin{equation*} I + I  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Is not idempotent, as $(2I)^2 = 4I$

Comment: In nimber arithmetic, $I+I=0$.  _That's_ where the claim works.

Comment: You mean [Grundy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) ?